# Getting selectedIndex on a userdefined variable - Works in IE not Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, selectedindex

I have the following function that populates HTML textfields depending on the users selection.  Since the number of references can be 1 to many I pass in the id of the reference they are updating.

I get the error on the line:

```
var IndexOfReferenceSelect = ReferenceSelect.selectedIndex;
```

that `ReferenceSelect` is `null`. How do I set `ReferenceSelect` in Firefox? I thought using `getElementById` would work. It does in IE but not Firefox.

```
function SelectReference(ReferenceNum){
    var i;
    var ReferenceSelect = document.getElementById("Reference_" + ReferenceNum);

    var Author      = document.getElementById("Author_Last_Name_" + ReferenceNum);
    var Title       = document.getElementById("Title_" + ReferenceNum);
    var Edition     = document.getElementById("Edition_" + ReferenceNum);
    var Publisher   = document.getElementById("Publisher_" + ReferenceNum);
    var Year1       = document.getElementById("Year_" + ReferenceNum);
    var Pages       = document.getElementById("Pages_" + ReferenceNum);

    var ReferenceList = new Array(<%=strBigListOfOptionTagGroups%>);

    var IndexOfReferenceSelect = ReferenceSelect.selectedIndex;

    var IndexOfReferences = ReferenceList[IndexOfReferenceSelect].split("|");

    Author.value    = IndexOfReferences[0];
    Title.value     = IndexOfReferences[1];
    Edition.value   = IndexOfReferences[2];
    Publisher.value = IndexOfReferences[3];
    Year1.value     = IndexOfReferences[4];
    if (IndexOfReferenceSelect == 0){
        Pages.value = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that ReferenceNum is being passed correctly when calling SelectReference, because document.getElementById works in all browsers.

Comment: This is the HTML that passes ReferenceNum:

                         <select name="Reference_1" id="Reference_1" onchange="javascript:SelectReference('1')" >

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.getElementById` is exactly the way to do. So the problem could be that the DOM is not properly loaded yet when you're tring to access to the element; or the `ReferenceNum` is not properly se; or that you set `name` attribute instead of `id`: in that case IE has a bug that doesn't makes differences between name or id, and it will returns the element, where the browsers that are following the standards will returns `null`.